# "No Jab No Job" --> Straight order, am I correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[**Reading this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/tech/m/971eb51d-bee5-3d94-9979-cc15bcd58b0c/biden%E2%80%99s-no-jab-no-job-order.html), there is a headline saying,

> Biden’s **no-jab-no-job order** creates quandary for nursing homes

So this would mean if the workers for nursing homes don't get vaccinated, they are straightly likely to be fired.

No jab ( sounds "like" "no job" )--> Just a straight punch. No meaning virtually.

I need a bit of confirmation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jab can be a straight punch or a needle prick/injection, therefore "no jab (unpricked by a needle, unvaccinated), no job (they will not be hired)"

Comment: Ah, I thought it totally on the contrary. Thanks.